# NavigationView:setCheckedItem not working for child item

Tags: android

I have the following menu ressource file (generated with androids Navigation Drawer Activity) and customized by me:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_users"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_following"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp" />
</group>

<item android:title="Foo">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_licences"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment_black_24dp" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Setting the first level items works as expected:

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
```

But setting a child menu item as checked, doesn't do anything.

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_about);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the generated layout by Android Studio. To check child items, I had to adjust the layout like this:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_users"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_following"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp" />
</group>

<item android:title="Foo">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_licences"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment_black_24dp" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: It's quite easy to mistakenly put <group android:checkableBehavior="single"> above <item android:title="Foo"> . Whoever is reading this, do pay head. The above solution works. Thank you very mate. Cheerio!

Answer (score 2):

Its because they are not under group tag , and they dont have property of `android:checkableBehavior="single"` .

Modify you code as

```
<item android:title="Foo">
<menu>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_licences"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment_black_24dp" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select an Item of the Navigation drawer in the onCreate Method or anywhere else in your application, you can use the code below:

> navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

The getItem(int index) method gets the MenuItem then you can call the setChecked(true);on that MenuItem, all you are left to do is to find out which element index does the default have, and replace the 0 with that index.

You can select(highlight) the item by calling

> onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));

---

You can refer to this as well :

[NavigationView with DrawerLayout setCheckedItem not working](http://www.developersite.org/102-76690-android)

Also you can add the menu as:

```
<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

     <item
       android:id="@+id/nav_home"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"/>

    <item
       android:id="@+id/nav_users"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <item
       android:id="@+id/nav_following"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp" />
</group>

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_licences"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution...

Use two line code, one is for **checked Item** of navigation drawer and second is for **selection of item** of sub-menu.

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_about);
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).getSubMenu().getItem(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your menu programatically you will have to do something similar to [@Abdul Kawee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579727/1572848)

```java
Menu.setGroupCheckable(...)
```